# How to retrieve information from SQLiteDatabase in android

Tags: android, android-intent, sqlite, android-manifest

I created an android application using eclipse. I used one button to store some information and another one to retrieve information from database. First one is working but when I press VIEW button to display data it says “Unfortunately MyDatabase has stopped”. I am ginving you all the information.
The main class SqlLiteExample.java :

```
public class SqlLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button sqlUpdate, sqlView;
EditText etName,etAge,etContact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlliteexample);
    sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
    etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
    etContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editContact);

    sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewbutton);
    sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.savebutton:
        boolean didWork = true;
        try{
        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String age = etAge.getText().toString();
        String contact = etContact.getText().toString();

        MyDB entry = new MyDB(SqlLiteExample.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name,age,contact);
        entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            didWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Error");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }finally{
            if(didWork){
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Updated");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
        }
        break;
    case R.id.viewbutton:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.DISPLAYRECORDS");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

}

To control database I used MyDB.java :

```
public class MyDB {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "persons_age";
public static final String KEY_CONTACT = "persons_contact";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AGE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CONTACT + "TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }       
}
public MyDB(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}
public MyDB open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}
public long createEntry(String name, String age, String contact) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    cv.put(KEY_CONTACT, contact);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_CONTACT};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iAGE = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
    int iCONTACT = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTACT);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iAGE) + " " + c.getString(iCONTACT) +"\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Another Activity to display info is DisplayRecords.java:

```
public class DisplayRecords extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
    MyDB info = new MyDB(this);

    try {
        info.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
}
```

}

The Main xml file is sqlliteexample.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/age" >
        </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContcat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/contact" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/save"/>"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Another layout to display… sqlview.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Names" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/age" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/contacts" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSQLinfo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/gt" >
</TextView>
```

And the manifest.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bysakiralam.mydatabase"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<compatible-screens></compatible-screens>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.SqlLiteExample"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayRecords" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.DISPLAYRECORDS" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Where is my mistake? plz help.
Contents of LogCat file:

```
07-11 16:46:11.312: E/Trace(668): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-11 16:46:15.531: D/gralloc_goldfish(668): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-11 16:46:32.695: I/Choreographer(668): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 12:26:37.454: I/Choreographer(668): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 12:26:40.614: I/Choreographer(668): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 12:26:43.694: D/dalvikvm(668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 81K, 8% free 2688K/2892K, paused 73ms+10ms, total 235ms
07-11 12:26:46.934: E/SQLiteLog(668): (1) table peopleTable has no column named persons_contact
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668): Error inserting persons_contact=wert persons_age=32 persons_name=sad
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table peopleTable has no column named persons_contact (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO peopleTable(persons_contact,persons_age,persons_name) VALUES (?,?,?)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.MyDB.createEntry(MyDB.java:68)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.SqlLiteExample.onClick(SqlLiteExample.java:46)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-11 12:26:46.984: E/SQLiteDatabase(668):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 12:26:54.745: I/Choreographer(668): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 12:26:56.694: E/SQLiteLog(668): (1) no such column: persons_age
07-11 12:26:56.745: D/AndroidRuntime(668): Shutting down VM
07-11 12:26:56.745: W/dalvikvm(668): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bysakiralam.mydatabase/com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.DisplayRecords}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: persons_age (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, persons_name, persons_age, persons_contact FROM peopleTable
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: persons_age (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, persons_name, persons_age, persons_contact FROM peopleTable
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.MyDB.getData(MyDB.java:73)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.DisplayRecords.onCreate(DisplayRecords.java:25)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-11 12:26:56.934: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  ... 11 more
07-11 12:27:01.954: I/Process(668): Sending signal. PID: 668 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is the error in the log file? Use LogCat to obtain the exception and post it in your question.

Comment: You need to post your logcat to your own question, not someone elses answer... Also thats not the logcat exception for your application. You need to filter the log by your application name and post the exception from it.

Comment: whats the point in posting your entire code. post the relevant code and the logcat. then we can help you out.. its tough to go thru each line of your code and find the error .

Comment: how to obtain that code@beniMathew

Comment: @Smith S Check the answer i posted.. that should solve ur error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change :**

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_AGE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_CONTACT + "TEXT NOT NULL);"

            );
```

**to**

```
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

            );
```

**Reason** : You were not putting space in following :

```
  KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +  KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

Comment: Not sure who gave you a -1. This is a solid answer that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your log cat when you run your application, it will inform you on what line and where the error occurred. That will give you a good idea of what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

CHANGE

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            **KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"**

            );
```

TO

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            **KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL)"
            );**
```

You had a small syntax error

Comment: Look carefully.. you will know the differnce

Comment: @PHIL.. TRY RUNNING THIS CODE AND FIND AN ERROR

Comment: @TARSEM.. I HAVE HIGLITED THE CODE THAT I EDITED AND THE CODE GIVEN.. HOPE YOU FIND THE DIFFERENCE NOW

Comment: @tarsem what did u even mean by that statement ?

Comment: SmitaS who asked the question was missing the blank space at 2 places and when you @benilMathew were giving the right answer you forget to put the semicolon !

Comment: but i think it will not create any problem ! so it should be right one now ! so +1 :)

Comment: first error in logcat is: 07-11 13:18:30.879: E/SQLiteLog(839): (1) table peopleTable has no column named persons_contact

Comment: one more thing how to add a TAB b/w two rows?

Comment: @smitha. it would be good if you could tell us how u solved ur error

Comment: @smitha Thank you.. if thats the case.. pls marked the answer corect so that ppl who downvoted would understand i actually had the right answer

Comment: one more thing how to add a TAB b/w two rows?

Comment: @smitha.s.. can you explain what you want ? Tabs in the sense while you view it in SQLite thru command prompt ?

Comment: @smitaS... http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html.. Try this link if you want help with Shell commands

Comment: @smitaS ok. That would be better

Comment: i cant upload pics.. search how to add tab between two rows while displaying data from sqlite

Comment: Like i asked you earlier.. Dsiplaying tabs for rows .  where in the **shell** or in **you app** ?

Comment: i am not getting what you are asking..in the emulator when i click view button then it displays the stored data which is not formatted. i.e more spaces b/w column names such as NAME, AGE, CONTACT and less space b/w values such as Methew 26 London

Comment: In that case you can edit your XML file which i assume you are using ListView layout to display your data.. Providing padding might solve that issue..

Comment: You should add  android:paddingLeft="5dip" to the first textview then  android:paddingLeft="10dip" to the next textview and so on

Comment: i have made some changes to your code.. i dont think it will be good posting here. where else can i post the the code i edited ?

Comment: else these are the changes             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"

Comment: make changes to android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"  as you like ie increase it or decrease it for each textview